# Generic out of work when Use RegistrationBuilder IN MEF

Tags: c#, generics, mef

I would like to just use RegistrationBuilder to create parts.

example:

```
public interface IModel
{
    String Name { get; }
}

public interface IRepository
{
}

class ModelOne : IModel
{
    public String Name { get { return "ModelOne"; } }
}

class ModelTwo : IModel
{
    public String Name { get { return "ModelTwo"; } }
}

public interface IRepository<TModel> : IRepository where TModel : IModel
{
}

public class Repository<TModel> : IRepository<TModel> where TModel : IModel
{
}

static void Main(String[] args)
{
    var builder = new RegistrationBuilder();
    builder.ForTypesDerivedFrom<IModel>()
        .Export()
        .Export<IModel>();
    builder.ForTypesDerivedFrom<IRepository>()
        .ExportInterfaces();
    var asmCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), builder);
    var container = new CompositionContainer(asmCatalog);
    var one = container.GetExportedValue<IRepository<ModelOne>>();
    var two = container.GetExportedValue<IRepository<ModelTwo>>();
}
```

I can not get the results(the one,the two) I want.

because when i use RegistrationBuilder the all type when wrapped in ProjectingType,but GetExportedValue method did not wrap Generic Parameters in ProjectingType.

My temporary solution is to delete the IsAssignableFrom method in ProjectingType. Now I can get the results(the one,the two) I want.

is there any good solution or correction?